# Link Progress bar to days/time remaining countdown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a deal page with countdown timer to show how much time is remaining to claim the offer. I have the countdown timer working to show how many days, hours, minutes and seconds are left, but would like to have a visual progress bar under the time that fills up based on the days left.

For example, the offer goes live July 1 and expires July 31. If the user loads the page on July 1, the progress bar would be at 0%. On July 31, the progress bar would be set to 100%.

I am currently using the progress bar styling and HTML code used by Bootstrap 3.

I've been trying to the width style property for "progress-bar" to the days remaining, but have not been able to get them to link up

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
 var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
 var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
 var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
 var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
return {
  'total': t,
 'days': days,
 'hours': hours,
 'minutes': minutes,
 'seconds': seconds
 };
 }
 
function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
var clock = document.getElementById(id);
 var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
 var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
 var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
 var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');
 
function updateClock() {
var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
 
 daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
 hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
 minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
 secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

if (t.total <= 0) {clearInterval(timeinterval); } } updateClock(); var timeinterval=setInterval(updateClock, 1000); } var deadline=new Date("july 31, 2019 23:59:59"); initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="clockdiv" style="font-weight:600;text-transform: uppercase">Time Remaining:<span class="days"></span>:<span class="hours"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span></div>
  <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom:8px;border-radius: 4px">
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" style="width:%;border-radius: 4px">
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo using

> Math.round(((today - start) / (end - start)) * 100) + '%';

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime, starttime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');
  
  var $progress = $('.progress-bar')

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
    
    var p = Math.round(((new Date() - starttime) / (endtime - starttime)) * 100) + '%';
    $progress.css('width', p);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }
  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}
var starttime = new Date("july 1, 2019 23:59:59");
var deadline = new Date("july 31, 2019 23:59:59");
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline, starttime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="clockdiv" style="font-weight:600;text-transform: uppercase">Time Remaining:<span class="days"></span>:<span class="hours"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span></div>

<div class="progress" style="margin-bottom:8px;border-radius: 4px">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" style="width:%;border-radius: 4px">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** It is not necessary to update progress bar every second, It's fine in minutes

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelector('.progress-bar')` and then use `.style.width = 'xx %'` to set the width.

I've refactored the code a bit to make it more readable :)

Working example:

```js
function Clock(id, startDate, endDate) {
  this.clock = document.getElementById(id);
  this.timeEl = this.clock.querySelector('.time');
  this.progressEl = this.clock.querySelector('.progress-bar');
  this.startDate = startDate;
  this.endDate = endDate;
  
  this.updateClock();
  this.interval = setInterval(this.updateClock.bind(this), 1000);
}
   
Clock.prototype.updateClock = function() {
  var rem = this.getTimeRemaining();
  
  // Update time element
  var duration = [
    rem.days,
    this.padLeft(rem.hours),
    this.padLeft(rem.minutes),
    this.padLeft(rem.seconds)
  ];
  this.timeEl.innerHTML = duration.join(":");
  
  // Update progress
  var progress = this.getProgress(rem.total);
  this.progressEl.style.width = (progress * 100) + "%";
  
  // Clear intervall when done
  if(rem.t === 0 && this.interval) {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    delete this.interval;
  }
};

Clock.prototype.padLeft = function(number) {
  return ('0' + number).slice(-2);
};

Clock.prototype.getTimeRemaining = function() {
  var t = this.endDate - new Date();
  if(t < 0) t = 0;

  return {
    total: t,
    days: Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
    hours: Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
    minutes: Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60),
    seconds: Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60)
  };
};

Clock.prototype.getProgress = function(remainingTime) {
  var totalTime = this.endDate - this.startDate;
  return 1 - (remainingTime / totalTime);
};

// Example. Replace startDate and endDate with your dates (30sec for demo)
var startDate = new Date();
var endDate = new Date(Date.now() + 30 * 1000);
new Clock("clockdiv", startDate, endDate);
```

```css
#clockdiv {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.progress {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.progress-bar {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    Time Remaining:
    <span class="time"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```